# Selecting subsets of a list containing a specific element

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I'm trying to generate all the subsets of a set containing a specific element.

For example, for the set {1, 2, 3, 4}, with the specific element I want inside each subset being 4, the required answer would be

```
{{4}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

My current code is to do `Select[Subsets[Range[n]], MemberQ[#, n] &]`, where for the above example we would have `n=4`. However, the code seems inefficient and my computer runs out memory for `n>25`. Is there a more efficient way to do so, or is this already the best?

NB: I will only need to work with one of the subsets at any point of time, but the `Select` code above doesn't seem to allow me to pick an arbitrary $i^{th}$ subset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to set aside that element before forming your `Subsets`, like so:

```
set = Range[25];
n = 9;
Timing[Append[#, n] & /@ Subsets[DeleteCases[set, n]];]
(* 14.8 s versus 47.6 s for the Select method *)
```

You can specify the $i^{\rm th}$ subset using the third argument to `Subsets`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution - I think it's similar in concept to that of kguler. Your `Append[#,n]& /@` was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another idea, piggybacking on existing Mathematica code for finding only some subsets.

```
subsetsWithSpecialMembers[set_, special_List, nspec_, s_] := 
Map[Join[#, special] &, 
Subsets[Complement[set, special], nspec, s]];

subsetsWithSpecialMembers[set_, special_List, nspec_] := 
Map[Join[#, special] &, Subsets[Complement[set, special], nspec]];

subsetsWithSpecialMembers[set_, special_List] := 
Map[Join[#, special] &, Subsets[Complement[set, special]]];

subsetsWithSpecialMembers[Range[4], {4}] (* original request*)

subsetsWithSpecialMembers[Range[4], {4}, {2, 4}, {3}](* just the third subset of subsets 
with length 2 through 4*)
```

Comment: My answer is quite similar to Xerxes but possibly a bit more general in that it permits multiple elements to be privileged.  His appears somewhat faster.

Comment: I believe Xerxes' code can be generalized to work in a similar way to yours by modifying the `DeleteCases` code slightly. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the same idea as in @Seth's answer implemented differently:

Making use of the various argument patterns [Subsets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subsets.html) accepts:

[image]

the following function joins with `member` each of the `number` subsets of `Complement[list,member]` with size =`size`:

```
 ClearAll[subsetsF];
 subsetsF[list_, members_, size_:All, number_:All] :=
 With[{list2 = (list /. Thread[members -> Sequence[]])}, 
  Join[#, members] & /@ Subsets[list2, size, number]]
```

Usage examples:

```
  subsetsF[Range[4],  {4}] (* op's example *)
  (* {{4}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)

  subsetsF[Range[4], {4}, {2, 3}] (* subsets containing 3 or 4 elements including 4 *)
  (* {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)

  subsetsF[Range[4], {4}, {2, 3}, -2] (* "last" 2 subsets with 3 or 4 elements including 4 *)
  (* {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: Hi @kguler, thank you for your answer. I do believe you meant `subsetsF` in your usage examples? Also, is it possible to generalize your solution if I want all subsets containing a set of specific elements? For instance, all subsets of `Range[4]` containing `{3,4}`.

Comment: @VincentTjeng, yes.. just corrected.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't mean to be pedantic about it, was slightly confused at first.